# WPF Datagrid Column not updating during edit

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a datagrid which has two templatecolumns using a ComboBox. The second of these needs to be populated dependant on the first.  Here is a stripped down example of my class:

```
public class Customer 
{
    public int ID { get;set; }
    // Other Fields
    public string DropdownValue1 { get;set; }
    public string DropdownValue2 { get;set; }
    public List<DropdownItem> Options1 { get;set; } // DropdownItem is another class of 3 strings called Text, Value and Group
    public List<DropdownItem> Options2 { get;set; }
    public List<DropdownItem> FilteredItems 
    {
        get { return Options2.Where(n => n.Group == DropdownValue1); }
    }
}
```

When getting data and creating a list for this class i.e. List and populating it, I set the options accordingly:

```
customer.ID = id;
DropdownValue1 = dropdown1;
DropdownValue2 = dropdown2;
Options1 = GetOptions1(); // i.e. returns List<DropdownItem> with manual populated items
Options2 = GetOptions2();
```

The ItemsSource of the datagrid is set to this collection and then the columns themselves are written like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Dropdown 1" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource WrappedColumnHeaderStyle}">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                                <MultiBinding>
                                                    <MultiBinding.Converter>
                                                        <local:DropdownConverter />
                                                    </MultiBinding.Converter>
                                                    <Binding Path="DropdownValue1" />
                                                    <Binding Path="Options1" />
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </TextBlock.Text>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding DropdownValue1}" SelectedValuePath="Value" DisplayMemberPath="Text" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Options1}"></ComboBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Dropdown 2" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource WrappedColumnHeaderStyle}">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                                <MultiBinding>
                                                    <MultiBinding.Converter>
                                                        <local:GroupDropdownConverter />
                                                    </MultiBinding.Converter>
                                                    <Binding Path="DropdownValue2" />
                                                    <Binding Path="Options2" />
                                                    <Binding Path="DropdownValue1" />
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </TextBlock.Text>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding DropdownValue2}" SelectedValuePath="Value" DisplayMemberPath="Text" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FilteredItems}"></ComboBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This all works ok, except when changing the first column, the second dropdown cell or edit template is not updated with correct values until coming off the row completely. It does update but not after the individual cell edit.

I added INotifyPropertyChanged to my class i.e. class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanged, and put the OnPropertyChanged() in the setter for both DropdownValue properties but this made no different.

How can I ensure the second column is updated as soon as the first column is changed without having to navigate off the row first?

Comment: You should also raise a property change notification for `FilteredItems` when value for first combobox is chagned.

Comment: @sthotakura as in: OnPropertyChanged("FilteredItems"); within the set of DropdownValue1?

Comment: Yes, that’s right!

Comment: @sthotakura sadly this made no difference, still need to go off the row and back again.